# what's the most efficient way to shuffle huge bit-vectors using GCC

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization

I have two very big bit vectors (about 1 GB each) and I want to shuffle them 
in the following fashion:

first bit vector:  `a[0], a[1], a[n]`
second bit vector: `b[0], b[1], b[n]`

It should result in something like:

```
c[0] = a[0]
c[1] = b[0] 
c[2] = a[1]
c[3] = b[1]
```

What’s the most efficient way to do that in C++, using the vector operations of the new Intel processors? I want to do this using GCC.

Comment: What have you tried ? Why is a naive loop using two `std::vector<bool>` not enough ?

Comment: So you need to make a third vector which will store the shuffle of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Why don' you use a bitset instead of bit vector, they are faster.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I did the loop but works way too slow. I have tried nothing more (I'm mathematician). I 'm reading the manuals of the instruction sets of the new Intel processors and I understand that it is possible to do high performance bit-vector shuffling operations but I'm confused on how to implement this using GCC. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @black yes. That's what I want to do. Thank you.

Comment: @GeorgeStefanopoulos May you show us the way you've used? Did auto vectorization work?

Comment: @GeorgeStefanopoulos looking at your example, do you mean interleave (i.e. alternate selection maintaining order) rather than shuffle (i.e. randomize the order)?

Comment: @Alan yes I do mean interleave. Btw, "shuffle" is the term also used in e.g. http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#shuffle

Comment: @GeorgeStefanopoulos a quick look at the [gcc website](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#using) suggests that auto-vectorization is applied whenever the -O3 optimization flag is used in the compilation.  It might be interesting to compile with `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2` as well to see if your basic for-loop version gets vectorized, and if not what error it throws.

Comment: by "bit vector" are you talking about `std::vector<bool>` or something else?

Comment: This is a very good question. Here are the "standard" solutions: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious — however, none of these are using the new fancy vector extensions, so they do not really answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

you could try rolling your own loop --

```
int ch1, ch2;
while ((ch1 = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF && (ch2 = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF) {
    int i, dst = 0;
    // assuming msb goes first
    for (i=7; i>=0; i--) {
        dst |= (ch1 & (1<<i)) << (2*i + 1);
        dst |= (ch2 & (1<<i)) << (2*i + 0);
    }
    putc(dst >> 8);
    putc(dst & 0xFF);
}
```

You can massage this a bit, unroll it, prefetch chunks into local arrays, process 16 bits in the loop, but it interleaves the bits in two bytes in 4 instructions per source bit (-O3 unrolled the loop).

If we assume two bytes take 150 cycles on a 3GHz processor, that's 40 MB/sec output from 2x20 MB/sec source data read, or 50 seconds for 2x1000 MB.  Feeding data to the loop, however, may cut into the throughput.